# Why doesn't www.linux.org.il look properly in MSIE 7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm the maintainer of http://www.linux.org.il/ and it doesn't look properly in Microsoft Internet Explorer 7. The problem I see is that the navigation bar appears to the top of the page's main text instead of to its right as in Firefox. Does anyone know how to fix it in MSIE 7 (and if possible - also in MSIE 6)?

I should note that in Firefox and other browsers, the navigation bar stays in place, when the page is scrolled, but I don't mind that in MSIE it will move along with the rest of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add float:right on your sidebar div. this will cause the content to get pulled up. not sure what impact on firefox will be;-)

I tested this using IE Developer Toolbar, I will caution that I have seen some changes work when you modify via this tool but not work when contained within the original markup. Hopefully this works for yea

Answer (score 0):

MSIE has flaky support for `position: fixed` in CSS. If this is what you are doing, then you many have to use JavaScript. If you are already using JavaScript, check the variables you are using. See [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow).